# Dynamic query for high charts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I was using highcharts - stacked column charts. I tried to create a dynamic query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid IN ".$full);
```

This was the query and the $full is defined as:

```
$que1 = mysql_query("SELECT productid from admin_levels WHERE level>1 AND userid=$UserID ORDER BY productid");
$op1="";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($que1))
{
foreach($row1 as $cell1)
{
$op1.="'".$cell1."',";
}
}
$temp1=strlen($op1)-1;
$op1=substr($op1,0,$temp1);
$full = "( ".$op1." )";
```

Comment: When you do `echo $full ;` what you see ? or just `echo $query;` ?

Comment: ('16','17','20','114','125') . I tried making it (16,17,20,114,125) too but doesn not work

Comment: if the product id is int, no need to quote them. Finally do not use `()` in the `$full = "( ".$op1." )";` just keep it as `$full = $op1;`, then in the final query `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid IN (".$full.")"`.

Comment: we did try but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can call the above queries in a single query like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid IN (SELECT productid from admin_levels WHERE level>1 AND userid=$UserID ORDER BY productid)")  or  die(mysql_error()) ;
```

I will suggest you not to use mysql statements because these are vulnerable. Instead of this you please try mysqli or PDO statements

Comment: Try now ...i forget to add " at last of line . I have edited it.

Comment: It should work ...have you set the variable $UserID  in the query.  you can write    or  die(mysql_error()) and find the error . Check the updated answer